# Alternative to ElementTree.iter() in Python 2.6

Tags: python, xml, iteration, elementtree, python-2.6

I am using ElementTree to parse XML files.

I was using Python 3.6, but now I have to shift my code to a machine having only Python 2.6. I made some of the necessary changes in syntax, but I am stuck at [`ET.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter), which does not exist in Python 2.6, and which I was using with no arguments to recursively parse an `ElementTree` object.

I tried to change `iter()` to [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall), but that asks for a parameter specifying a match to filter elements by. I also tried simply doing

```
for child in element:
    # ... etc.
```

… but that only returns the children at the first level under `element`, not all of its descendants (which is what I need).

How can I recursively get all the elements in Python 2.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ET.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) was introduced in Python 2.7, to replace [`ET.getiterator()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getiterator) … which, although deprecated since then, remains [available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getiterator) up to and including the current Python 3.x release.

In many cases, `ET.getiterator()` can be used as a drop-in replacement for `ET.iter()` if Python 2.6 compatibility is required.

**However:** it's important to note that, although they're often interchangeable in practice, these methods are ***not*** the same: `ET.iter()` returns an iterator, while `ET.getiterator()` returns a list:

```
>>> tree.getiterator()
[<Element 'root' at 0x...>, <Element 'sub1' at 0x...>, <Element 'sub2' at 0x...>]
>>> tree.iter()
<_elementtree._element_iterator object at 0x...>
```

… with all of the potential implications for performance and functionality that this difference implies.